# My Join statement isn't working

Tags: mysql

I need help with a sql statement.

table users:

```
user_id    name
----------------------
1          joe
2          sam
5          tammy
6          jade
10         tony
```

table a1:

```
id    user_id    year    approved
----------------------------------
1       5         2012       1
2       6         2012       0
3       6         2013       1
4       5         2013       1
5       10        2012       0
6       10        2013       0
```

I need to return all 5 user_id wither or not they have an entry in table a1 and I need fields: a1.id, users.user_id, users.name, a1.year, a1.approved from the join.

My attempt:

```
select a1.id, users.user_id, users.name, a1.year, a1.approved from users 
LEFT JOIN a1 as a1 ON a1.user_id = users.user_id
```

Im stuck.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "isnt working"?

Comment: Create an SQL fiddle and explain what result you are expecting from your query.

Comment: Your code appears to work as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8f13/1/0

Comment: works as expected here as well - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a83e/2